# how can i use input.properties files like concept in TCL script

Tags: tcl

in ANt script we access properties file as below
`<property file="input.properties"/>`
in perl script we access properties file as below
`do "config.cfg";`

same way how can i access properties file in TCL script.
Can anyone help me out pls?
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if you want it as dumb as in Perl, just `source` the file in Tcl.

Configuration file sample (named `config.tcl`):

```
# Set "foo" variable:
set foo bar
```

To load this configuration file:

```
source config.tcl
```

After `source`-ing, you can access your variable `foo` in your script.

---

As with perl, a malicious user might put something like

```
exec rm -rf ~
```

in your "config file" and wish you all the good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest mechanism is to either make it a script or to make it the contents of an array. Here's how to do the latter while still supporting comments:

```
proc loadProperties {arrayName fileName} {
    # Put array in context
    upvar 1 $arrayName ary

    # Load the file contents
    set f [open $fileName]
    set data [read $f]
    close $f

    # Magic RE substitution to remove comment lines
    regsub -all -line {^\s*#.*$} $data {} data

    # Flesh out the array from the (now clean) file contents
    array set ary $data
}
```

Then you'd use it like this:

```
loadProperties myProps ~/myapp.props
if {[info exists myProps(debug)] && $myProps(debug)} {
    parray myProps
}
```

With a file in your home directory (called `myapp.props`) like this:

```
# Turn on debug mode
debug true
# Set the foos and the bars
foo "abc"
bar "Harry's place downtown"
```

You can do a lot more complicated than that, but it gives you an easy format to get going with.

---

If you prefer to use an executable configuration, just do:

```
# Define an abstraction that we want users to use
proc setProperty {key value} {
    # Store in a global associative array, but could be anything you want
    set ::props($key) $value
}
source ~/myapp_config.tcl
```

If you want to restrict the operations to ones that won't cause (much) trouble, you need a slightly more complex approach:

```
interp create -safe parser
proc SetProp {key value} {
    set ::props($key) $value
}
# Make a callback in the safe context to our main context property setter
interp alias parser setProperty {} SetProp
# Do the loading of the file. Note that this can't be invoked directly from
# within the safe context.
interp invokehidden parser source [file normalize ~/myapp_config.tcl]
# Get rid of the safe context; it's now surplus to requirements and contaminated
interp delete parser
```

Safety has pretty low overhead.

Comment: You _could_ set global variables from the properties loader, but that's probably a bad idea. If loading a script, you _might_ consider using a safe interpreter with a strict profile of what commands are exposed. Or you might not bother; it's the user's application after all and if they want to break it, they can just that. :-)

Comment: i am new to Tcl but it's seems complex in term of properties Gruop name  and valsue access. in perl it's easy. just we need to define in config.cfg file like `$var = "test";` and we can user direct that value in script as `print $var`
in same way in Tcl i want to use like name = "value".

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of perls

```
$var = "test";
```

is in Tcl

```
set var "test"
```

So if you want it as easy as in Perl, I suggest [kostix answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15878232/845414).

---

But you could also try to use [dicts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) as config file:

This will look like

```
var {hello world}
other_var {Some data}
foo {bar baz}
```

I personally love using this, it allows even nesting:

```
nestedvar {
    subvar {value1}
    subvar2 {value2}
}
```

And comments: <sup><sub>Kind of a hack, in fact has the key `#`</sub></sup>

```
# {This is a comment}
```

Parsing:

```
 set fd [open config.file]
 set config [read $fd]
 close $fd
 dict unset config #; # Remove comments.
```

Access:

```
 puts [dict get $config var]
 puts [dict get $config nestedvar subvar]
```

---

But if you want really something like `$var = "foo";` (which is valid Perl code but not Tcl), then you have to parse this file yourself.

An example:

```
proc parseConfig {file} {
    set fd [open $file]
    while {[gets $fd line] != -1} {
         if {[regexp {^\s*\$([^\s\=]+)\s*\=\s*(.*);?$} $line -> var value]} {
              # The expr parses funny stuff like 1 + 2, \001 inside strings etc.
              # But this is NOT perl, so "foo" . "bar" will fail.
              set ::$var [expr $value]
         }
    }
}
```

Downside: does not allow multi-line settings, will throw an error if there is an invalid value, and allows command injection (but you Perl solution does that too).